# Google Fit Integrated within Android App Sign In Partially Works

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am working on an app that links to Google Fit (to upload data and to download other data). At one point in the app, the user is prompted to connect to Google Fit. This is done by the code shown below. For some flavors of this app, we see a strange bug. The Google Fit Sign In screen will appear, but when the user chooses an account, it will NOT prompt the user with more info and will not connect the user to Google Fit. Trying to determine if this is something in my app that I'm doing wrong or if this is a new bug. Has anyone else encountered this and/or solved it?

```
GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                            this,
                            GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE,
                            getLastSignedInAccount(getActivityBase()),
                            fitnessOptions);
```

When looking through the logs, I noticed that when it works, these are both called:

```
ActivityManager: START u0 {act=null typ=null flg=0x0 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity}} ActivityManager: START u0 {act=null typ=null flg=0x0 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.signin.activity.ConsentActivity}}
```

But when it doesn't work, the ConsentActivity is never started. It appears that Google is responsible for firing off this intent, but there isn't any logging that says why this is NOT fired off.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to help decode the error:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(GOOGLE_TAG, "onActivityResult requestCode=" + requestCode + " and resultCode=" + resultCode);

    int unmaskedRequestCode = requestCode & 0xFFFF;

    if (unmaskedRequestCode == googleFitConnect.GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(intent);
        int status = result.getStatus().getStatusCode();
        Log.d(TAG, "GoogleSignInResult status code string is: " + GoogleSignInStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(status));
        Log.d(TAG, "GoogleSignInResult status code is: " + status);
    }

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (unmaskedRequestCode == googleFitConnect.GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            Log.d(GOOGLE_TAG, "request code is google fit code");
            //connect to Google Fit
        } else {
            Log.d(GOOGLE_TAG, "request code is NOT google fit code");
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

For some flavors/environments, I got an error code of 10 which means DEVELOPER_ERROR (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes.html#DEVELOPER_ERROR). Turns out the package name entered in the Google API Console had a spelling mistake.

For other flavors/environments, I got an error code of 12500 which means SIGN_IN_FAILED (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInStatusCodes.html#SIGN_IN_FAILED). The documentation didn't help narrow this down. In the Google API Console, I then completed the Consent Screen and hit Save. Once I hit the "Save" button, those environments no longer failed. It appears that when adding new OAuth 2.0 Credentials, it is now required to complete the Consent Screen. This is noted in their documentation, however, I want to point that ONE of the flavors worked fine the whole time. That flavor's OAuth Credentials had been added prior to Google changing all of this, so it appears to have been grandfathered in to still work if the Consent Screen had not been completed (thus using Google's default Consent Screen).